# Inserting CMOS battery upside down

Tags: computer-architecture, motherboard

What happens when CMOS battery is inserted upside down? What is it capable of damaging? Power supply, entire motherboard or specific ICs.

Comment: What is a "Complimentary Metal Oxide Semiconductor" battery?  Are you talking about the coin cell that backs up a Time of Day clock?  If so, it is difficult to do any damage with most coin cell battery holders.  Most coin cell battery holder only make contact to the bottom and side of a coin cell.  If the coin cell were inserted upside down, likely only one side of the battery would come into contact with the two battery holder contacts.

Answer (score 3):

A long time ago, I designed computer motherboards. These were intel-based 6u compact PCI single board computers for telco applications. We always put two current limiting elements between the battery and the CMOS power input. One of the current limiting elements was always a Schottky diode, and the other one was a resistor (such as maybe a 100 Ohm resistor.. don't quite remember). Assuming motherboards still follow this practice, a backwards battery should not cause any damage at all.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* damage the CMOS RTC chip. Since its main job is to keep track of the date/time and the BIOS password (if used), it will not affect start-up, but before BIOS is done and loads in the OS it may give a low battery warning and/or request that you reset the time.

It may boot completely and Windows/Apple/Linux will ask you to reset the date/time. The type 2032 coin cell has a life of about 6 to 10 years under ideal conditions, and that is the only IC it runs. If you run into date/time issues or the OS restarts over and over again, have a computer repair shop replace the RTC chip (Real-Time Clock).

Comment: The shelf-life of a 2032 is not even 10 to 15 years. And storage at high temperature can reduce the shelf-life to 1 year if it is in a computer that runs 24/7. Self discharge goes up dramatically with temperature.

Comment: @mkeith. Ok, I will accept the wide variance in life, but I had 6 Dell 690 workstations and all needed new RTC batteries at about 8 years of age. Will modify answer.

Comment: There may be better batteries available nowadays. I am not sure. I have not followed coin-cell specifications. But I definitely remember that around year 2000, you would be lucky to get 3 years out of a hot spare stored at 40C. (A hot spare blade that could activate immediately if the primary blade failed... a seamless fail-over thing for high reliability).

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleague did this mistake and we faced the following problems.Date was showing future date..example 2252 year and we were not able to change it to current date.If u fix upside down CMOS battery does not get fixed properly and ur bios settings gets changed frequently.I got some BIOS related errors also.Never fix the CMOS battery upside down

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).